# Linux bash to compare two files but the second file must be find

Tags: linux, bash

I have a batch that integrates an xml file time to time but could happens daily. After it integrates it puts in a folder like `/archives/YYMMDD(current day)`. The problem is if the same file is integrated twice. So I need a script what verifys the file (with diff command its possible but risky to make a bottleneck) but the problem is I can't find to resolve how to make to give the second files location.

P.S. I can't install on the server anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux can't run batch files. Are you looking for a bash solution?

Comment: Sorry for the misspell. Yes a bash solution.

Comment: Use `cmp` to compare files.

Comment: thank you. i resolved with chksum but can't find a way how to identify the second file. I mean after the file is loaded it is moved in a folder like YYYYMMDD. The problem is the file is coming randomly so i need to find somehow the last recent file.